# How does one make Console2 resize to a size greater than the primary display?

Tags: windows, console2

Console2 won't go over 44 rows on this machine, for some reason. Oddly, that's about the vertical size of the monitor on the left, but much much smaller than the size of the monitor on the right, which is where I'm trying to display the larger console.

Answer (score 3):

Console2 is only a wrapper around an invisible Windows Console window (due to the architecture of Windows console functions), so its size is the same as of that hidden window's - which is still on the primary display. Somewhere in the menus of Console2, you'll find the "Hide console window" option - use it to reveal the hidden console, then drag it to the secondary monitor.

Comment: Doesn't work. I even tried making that console window bigger directly by dragging it onto the second monitor and dragging the Windows console larger. The Console2 window still won't get bigger.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem with my own ConEmu (Console Emulator).
It was solved (programmatically) by decreasing font size in real console.

In Console2 (if you dont want try ConEmu) you may try to Show console window and manually change size of its font (4x6 for example) and then resize GUI window.

The idea is that font in real console **must** be noticible smaller than in GUI window.

Comment: Is this what you're talking about? http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/ That looks awesome. Giving it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

1. View->Console Window
2. Right click the console window's title bar and
   select Properties
3. Change the width and height

Doing the above will affect the size of Console2 window.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can get Console2 to have a buffer width much wider than  screen width, but you can't set it from the console settings->console window, which limits width to 200 (at least on my PC).

Instead you manually edit the console.xml file, (will be found in same directory as the console2 executable I think)

see the line at the very top of the file containing   buffer_columns=

set buffer_columns to whatever you want, I used 600,  and save the file.

restart Console2, and you will find it now has a horizontal scroll bar.

Great for looking a long lines of debug as they no longer wrap.

hope it helps,
John